# Error in connecting flutter to mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, dart, strapi

[image: second screenshot]
Please anyone, help me im stucked in this error ; "***Connection test failed: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.eventyapp-shard-00-00.uikjc.mongodb.net***"

[image: image of the mentioned error]

Comment: What's the port?

Comment: as in host address ;for ip i left is as "assess from anywhere"

Comment: @OrAssayag pls help me here is the second screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJIQ9.png

Comment: Use the connection string format provided by MongoDB Atlas

Comment: as in which place please specify, i kind of noob to mongodb atlas , i really dont understand, do you mean i should use the full connection string  in the "host filed" instead of using the "@eventyapp-shard-00-00.uikjc.mongodb.net"